# JSF Ajax working platform dependend

Tags: ajax, maven, jsf-2

i am developing a little application at work using jsf for the output.
Basically, the application gets called with an url-parameter, uses this to query a soap-interface and a database for more data and then calculates some recommended offerings.

I implemented the calculations based on some stubs for the interfaces, then implemented the queries in a branch - and noticed that ajax stopped working.
I use ajax to update the list of recommendations based on a filter input.

The bad thing: Even when resetting to my stable branch, it won't work again.
Right now i think it might be maven, based on following experiment:

1. I installed a fresh server instance (a nightly build of glassfish 5.0.1) on my remote machine (running debian).
2. I deployed a build of the stable branch with my jenkins

   -->Everything works fine!
3. I then installed a fresh instance of the same glassfish-zip on my local machine, copied the .war from the remote machine to the local instance

   -->Everything works fine!
4. Lastly, i checked out the stable branch in Eclipse, started the maven (m2e) build and deployed the .war on my local machine

   -->Ajax is not working, nothing happens.

I just don't get it, since maven should run machine independent, at least i thought. I already set the encoding to UTF-8, so there should be no platform dependencies.

I implemented some trace loggings and can see, that the method in the backing bean are not even called. There are no errors logged.

I'm thankful for every hint and will gladly provide more information if it would be helpful. Some initial informations are appended below.

Cheers

Tim

---

I use java 8, glassfish 5.0.1, eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) with m2e and egit.

Here is a part of the filterbars' xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
<label for="drop" class="toggle">Angebote filtern &#9662;</label>
<h:panelGroup id="filterleiste">
            <h:form id="filterleiste_hForm">
                <p id="filtertitel">Filterauswahl</p>
                <p id="filtererklärung">Hier kannst du Filter auswählen, um die Angebote zu finden, die dich interessieren.</p>

                <!-- FILTERFRAGE EMPFEHLUNG -->
                <h:panelGroup class="filterfrage" id="filterfrage_empfehlung">
                    <div class="filterfrage_header">Empfehlungen:</div>
                    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{resultpage.filter.zeigeNurEmpfehlungen}" layout="pageDirection" immediate="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="nur meine Empfehlungen anzeigen"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="alle Angebote anzeigen"/>
                        <f:ajax event="click"/>
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <!-- FILTERFRAGE BEREITS BESUCHT -->
                <h:panelGroup class="filterfrage" id="filterfrage_besucht">
                    <div class="filterfrage_header">Bereits besuchte Angebote:</div>
                    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{resultpage.filter.zeigeBesuchte}" layout="pageDirection" immediate="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="anzeigen"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="ausblenden"/>
                        <f:ajax event="click"/>
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandButton type="button" class="button filterbutton" value="Filter anwenden">
                    <f:ajax render=":angebotsdarstellung" listener="#{resultpage.updateView}"/>
                </h:commandButton>

                <!-- FILTERFRAGE THEMA -->
                <label for="filterklapper_themen" class="klapper_unterfilter">Themen filtern &#9662;</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="filterklapper" id="filterklapper_themen" />               
                <div id="filterklapper_themen" class="filterklapper">
                    <h:panelGroup class="filterfrage" id="filterfrage_themen">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{resultpage.filter.zeigeAlleThemen}">
                            <f:ajax listener="#{resultpage.filter.zeigeAlleThemenClick}" render="filterfrage_themen"/>
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        <label class="filterfrage_antwortcontainer exclusive_item">
                            alle Themen
                        </label>
                        <!-- Angebotsthemen -->
                        <ui:repeat var="thema" value="#{resultpage.filter.alleThemen}" varStatus="status">
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{resultpage.filter.themenGewaehlt[status.index]}">
                                <f:ajax listener="#{resultpage.filter.zeigeEinzelneThemenClick}" render=":filterleiste_hForm:filterfrage_themen"/>
                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            <h:outputLabel class="filterfrage_antwortcontainer filterfrage_eingerueckt" rendered="#{thema.isUnterbereich}">#{thema.darstellung}</h:outputLabel>
                            <h:outputLabel class="filterfrage_antwortcontainer" rendered="#{!thema.isUnterbereich}">#{thema.darstellung}</h:outputLabel>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <h:commandButton type="button" class="button filterbutton" value="Filter anwenden">
                        <f:ajax render=":angebotsdarstellung" listener="#{resultpage.updateView}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </div>
               [...]
            </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

Marked by [...], i've cut out some parts which are essentially the same as below "FILTERFRAGE THEMA", programmatically building checkboxes from enums.

The above composition is included in the mainpage, which only builds the structure around the filterbar (filterleiste.xhtml) and the part showing the filterresults (angebotsleiste.xhtml).

```html
<h:html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
<!-- includings css files and setting metadata -->
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <div class="container-wrap">
  <div class="container">

   <!-- some static html -->
   <section>
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/filterleiste.xhtml" </ui:include>
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/angebotscontainer.xhtml"></ui:include>
   </section>
   <!-- some more html -->
  </div>
 </div>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

Here is the backing bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "resultpage", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
@Data
public class ResultPage {
List<Empfehlung> gefilterteEmpfehlungen;
List<Empfehlung> alleEmpfehlungen;
private AngebotsSelector angebotsSelector;
private Umfrageergebnis umfrageergebnis;
boolean tempBool;
FilterObjekt filter;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ResultPage.class.getName());

public ResultPage() throws KfkException {
    this.updateAll(null);
    this.filter = new FilterObjekt();
    this.gefilterteEmpfehlungen = this.filter.filtereEmpfehlungen(alleEmpfehlungen);
}

public void updateAll(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws KfkException {
    LOGGER.trace("Aktualisiere Datenbasis");
    this.angebotsSelector = Guice.createInjector(new KfkModul()).getInstance(AngebotsSelector.class);
    this.alleEmpfehlungen = this.angebotsSelector.ermittleEmpfehlungen(0);
    this.umfrageergebnis = this.angebotsSelector.getUmfrageergebnis();
}

public void updateView(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    //this does not appear in the log
    LOGGER.debug(String.format("Updating view on filter object %S", this.filter.toString()));
    this.gefilterteEmpfehlungen = this.filter.filtereEmpfehlungen(alleEmpfehlungen);
}
}
```

The FilterObjekt class in the background basically just holds all attributes for which checkboxes are checked and then reduces a given List according to those attributes.
So i excluded a lot of methods which are by fact not called, because the methods calling them are not called themselves.

```
@Data
public class FilterObjekt {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(FilterObjekt.class.getName());

    private Map<Integer, Boolean> themenGewaehlt;
    private boolean zeigeAlleThemen;
    private final ArrayList<Angebotsthemen> alleThemen = new ArrayList<Angebotsthemen>(
        Arrays.asList(Angebotsthemen.values()));

    private Map<Integer, Boolean> aufwaendeGewaehlt;
    private boolean zeigeAlleAufwaende;
    private final ArrayList<Zeitspannen> alleAufwaende = new ArrayList<Zeitspannen>(
        Arrays.asList(Zeitspannen.values()));

    private Map<Integer, Boolean> formateGewaehlt;
    private boolean zeigeAlleFormate;
    private final ArrayList<Formate> alleFormate = new ArrayList<Formate>(Arrays.asList(Formate.values()));

    private Map<Integer, Boolean> zeitraeumeGewaehlt;
    private boolean zeigeAlleZeitraeume;
    private final ArrayList<Zeitraeume> alleZeitraeume = new ArrayList<Zeitraeume>(Arrays.asList(Zeitraeume.values()));

    private boolean zeigeNurEmpfehlungen;
    private boolean zeigeBesuchte;

    public List<Empfehlung> filtereEmpfehlungen(List<Empfehlung> recommendationList) {
        LOGGER.traceEntry(String.format("Filtere %s Empfehlungen", recommendationList.size()));
        ArrayList<Empfehlung> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Empfehlung recom : recommendationList) {
            if (this.empfehlungPasstFilter(recom))
                result.add(recom);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the browser console? What about debugging it in eclipse? Set up a break point in the `FacesServlet` class (you'll need to download Mojarra source code, eclipse does it automatically) and see if it gets hit. You could also set up an `h:messages` tag in the view and see if you've got any kind of message there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I get no messages in the browser console or h:messages tag. I'll try setting up the debugging, right now i have eclipse not integrated with glassfish, because last time i tried it ruined my glassfish config. I'll write again.

Answer (score 0):

after another reinstallation from scratch it suddenly works again.
I have literally no idea, what changed since last time, however i have no time to investigate any further and therefore guess it was some mistake on my side.